# Strange behavior in PHP + MySQL (Yii2)

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I need your help and advice.

I have a program that show information about users. Every an hour system (based Yii2) takes infromation from external system by SOAP protocol. Response constists over 8000 rows, that why i chunked response by 1000 rows and repeat request until get all rows (execution time near 30-45 seconds). Each response i store in table **user_temp** (MySQL) by **batchInsert** method (Yii2). Before storing i truncate table **user_temp**. After save data, i truncate data from main table **user** and insert from temporary table **user_temp** by query

```
INSERT INTO user SELECT * FROM user_temp
```

Sometimes query is success, but often is fail with error:
    **'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry \'1\' for key \'PRIMARY\' The SQL being executed was:   `INSERT INTO user SELECT * FROM user_temp'`**

Tables scheme for user_temp and user is same  (migration)

```
$this->createTable('user', [
        'id'                 => 'pk',
        'object1'           => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'object2'           => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'object3'           => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'ind_achivement'    => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'type_document'     => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'is_benefit'        => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'is_olymp'          => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'is_target'         => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'is_enrolled'       => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'priority'          => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'order'             => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'oop_base'          => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'is_expelled'       => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'enrollee_code'     => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'enrollee_name'     => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'total_balls'       => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER, 
        'is_concurs_out'    => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'is_rec_by_priority'=> Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'agreement_enroll'  => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'cg_code'           => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'date_update'       => Schema::TYPE_TIMESTAMP.' NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    ]);
```

code:

```
public function actionStart($token = null)
{
    if(!is_null($token) && ($token === Yii::$app->params['token'])){

        try{
            set_time_limit(0);

            $this->countRows('user_temp');
            $this->truncateTable('user_temp');
            $this->countRows('user_temp');
            $this->delayWithCheck('user_temp', 3);

            $again  = true;
            $step   = 1000;
            $stepNumber = 1;

            $config = new SoapConfig(Yii::$app->params['wsdl_url'], Yii::$app->params['wsdl_login'], Yii::$app->params['wsdl_password']);


            while($again){

                $sn = ($stepNumber - 1) * $step + 1;
                $sl = $stepNumber * $step;

                $client = new SoapClient($config, 'Rating', [
                    'NumberPK' => Yii::$app->params['numberPC'],
                    'From'               => $sn,
                    'To'              => $sl
                ]);

                $abiturients    = Util::toArray($client->getResponse()->RatingRow);
                $dateTime       = str_replace('T', ' ', $client->getResponse()->DateUpdate);
                $count = count($abiturients);

                $batchAbiturients = Util::prepareEnrolleToBatchInsert($abiturients, $dateTime);

                $this->addUsers($batchAbiturients);

                if($count < $step){
                    $again = false;
                }

                $stepNumber++;
                unset($client);
            }

            $this->truncateTable('user');
            $this->countRows('user');
            $this->delayWithCheck('user', 3);
            $this->copyTable('user_temp', 'user');

            $this->countRows('user_temp');
            $this->countRows('user');
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            VarDumper::dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        echo 'token not exist or invalid';
    }
}
protected function truncateTable($table = null)
{
    if(!$table){
        throw new \BadMethodCallException("must be name for Table");
    }
    $db = Yii::$app->db;

    $trnasaction = $db->beginTransaction();
    try{
        $rows = $db->createCommand('TRUNCATE TABLE '.$table)->execute();
        $trnasaction->commit();

        echo 'Table '.$table.' was truncated';
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        $trnasaction->rollBack();

        throw $e;
    }
}
protected function delayWithCheck($tableForCheck, $sec = 3)
{
    $check = true;
    $alert = 0;
    while($check){
        $countRows = (new Query())->from($tableForCheck)->count();
        if((int)$countRows === 0){
            $check = false;
        }

        if($alert === 10){
            throw new \Exception('Long query execute from '.$tableForCheck);
        }

        echo '<div>Delay: '.$countRows.' iteration</div>';
        sleep($sec);
        $alert++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add you more code, especially the truncate action, so that people have the information they need to correctly answer

Comment: added method code to question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert data that already is in the user table. As id is your primary key you are getting that error.

If the info from the external application is leading, then its easy and you can truncate the whole table, or if you have more complex requirements, update the already existing record. Thats up to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but before insert i truncate table user. I count rows in user table and get 0, but error with SQLSTATE[23000] rise up.

Comment: Add the table structure of both tables and some example records to your question